# Proper use of External DTD for XML

Tags: xml, validation, external, dtd

I have the following article.dtd

```
<!ELEMENT ARTICLE (HEADLINE,BYLINE,LEAD,BODY,NOTES)>
<!ELEMENT HEADLINE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT BODY (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST ARTICLE AUTHOR CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

and article.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ARTICLE SYSTEM "article.dtd">
<ARTICLE AUTHOR="T. Daniel">
    <HEADLINE>Title</HEADLINE>
    <BODY>Details</BODY>
</ARTICLE>
```

I open the xml file using Google Chrome browser, and when I'm accessing the page source I'm only getting the contents of the article.xml.

Isn't the page source supposed to combine the two files (show both document type definition and the xml document) ? And if so, why isn't that happening in my example? If not, how should I check if my xml is written according to the dtd file I want?

Mention: article.dtd and article.xml are in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Isn't the page source supposed to combine the two files (show both document type definition and the xml document) ?*

No, it is not supposed to combine the two files.

Most browsers do not load external DTDs. I could not find a definite reference for Chrome, but I think it's similar to how it works for Mozilla/Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XML_in_Mozilla#DTDs_and_Other_External_Entities).

> *how should I check if my xml is written according to the dtd file I want?*

Run it through a proper validator, for example [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) (a command line tool that comes with [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/index.html)):

```
$ xmllint --valid article.xml
```

Output from this command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ARTICLE SYSTEM "article.dtd">
<ARTICLE AUTHOR="T. Daniel">
    <HEADLINE>Title</HEADLINE>
    <BODY>Details</BODY>
</ARTICLE>
article.xml:6: element ARTICLE: validity error : Element ARTICLE content does not follow the DTD, expecting (HEADLINE , BYLINE , LEAD , BODY , NOTES), got (HEADLINE BODY )
</ARTICLE>
          ^
```